# How to read audio video stream using node js

Tags: node.js

I am looking to read audi/video stream using nodejs, haven't found any thing that explains how to achieve this.

Please advice how this can be done

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Do you want to multiplexe, pipeline the data ?

Comment: i want to read it and store it in bytes

Comment: When you only read and write bytes you do not need to decode the stream, so basically make a read stream and pipe it to write stream. Something like here https://gist.github.com/westonplatter/7617441.

Answer (score 1):

**VidStreamer.js** A simple streamer for Flash and HTML5-style videos. Supports HTTP pseudostreaming and works with JW Player's bitrate switching.

you can install it using

```
npm install vid-streamer
```

then give your audio/video files path in config/vidStreamer.json

if it not work then clone the `https://github.com/meloncholy/vid-streamer.git` repository and make appropriate configuration. Sample configuration

```
 {
    "mode": "development",
    "forceDownload": false,
    "random": false,
    "rootFolder": "/path/to/videos/",
    "rootPath": "videos/",
    "server": "VidStreamer.js/0.1.4"
}
```

To make a standalone video streamer, try something like this

```
var http = require("http");
var vidStreamer = require("vid-streamer");

var app = http.createServer(vidStreamer);
app.listen(3000);
console.log("VidStreamer.js up and running on port 3000");
```